# 2nd time MOMMY Muscovy Duck had a clutch of eggs in my mulch bed!

Tags: mulch

I don't want Mommy to lay a 3rd Clutch!!!  What can I do to deter this from happening again?  They are cute and ALL when they hatch, but this 2nd Clutch ... she left one little one behind and I'm waiting for the Muscovy Rescue to come and get lil' "LEFTY"  LOL

Comment: Have you tried fencing off the area?

Comment: So, fresh eggs are delivered to your garden?  Duck eggs are described as "rich" compared to chicken eggs, I find them very similar in something like an omelet  . As each one is delivered put it in the refrigerator until you have the number you want . Sitting in the nest a few days make no difference.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - I agree duck eggs are good eating . No need to put them in a refrigerator if room temp is 22 degrees or so (ie comfortable human temp). Eggs need temps in the 30's.  Also, crack them into a seperate cup just to be safe.